# Oracle: How to return a partial result only?

Tags: sql, oracle

Im using an Oracle database.

In my query 100 rows are fetched. If I want to filter rows between rownum 50 and 60, what would be the query?

```
SELECT EMPLID, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON 
from JOB where emplid ='12345'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most people will commonly tell you to use ROWNUM, to do this, however the more succinct way is the use the row_number() analytic function.

```
select EMPLID, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON
from
(
SELECT EMPLID, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON, row_number() over (order by emplid) rn
from JOB where emplid ='12345'
)
where rn between 50 and 60;
```

Using the row_number function allows you to order the results AND number them in a single query, then you just need one wrapper query to get the rows you need.

Comment: Not true: just because it LOOKS like a query within a query within a query, it doesn't mean Oracle implements it like that.  I just tested each method 10,000 times and they ran in 69 and 78 ms (yours was the slower as it happens, but the difference is insignificant).  Explain Plan shows what happens

Comment: On my system the times are insignificant both run in the 1.5 ms range on my table, however the row_number's syntax is cleaner and doesn't require two inline views.  See Tom Kyte, http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/07-jan/o17asktom.html

Comment: Agreed - it was the assertion that yours was "the more efficient" way that I was calling you on!  They are to all intents and purposes equally efficient.

Comment: In fact, if you remove the "more efficient" claim from your answer, I'll vote it up!

Comment: I would expect that the rownum method is potentially more efficient, as the optimizer is more likely to recognise that an index-based access method to return the ordered rows would be more efficient than getting all the rows and calculating a ROW_NUMBER.

Comment: @Tony, when comparing runs, keep in mind that Chad's version stops processing the inner subquery after fetching 60 records, whereas Nick's has to compute the "row_number" for *all* records in the subquery.  I prefer Nick's analytic solution, but it will run slower as the JOB table grows larger.

Comment: Edited per everyone's suggestions.

Comment: @uglysmurf: I don't think that's correct - my tests (see my answer) were on a pretty large table (copy of all_objects) and the autotrace plans show a STOPKEY in both cases.  Of course, the results may be different in older Oracle versions.

Comment: @Tony, thanks for pointing that out and setting me straight!  I thought stopkey only worked with rownum...it looks like Oracle added an analytic stopkey named "window nosort stopkey" in 10.2...pretty smart!  More info here:  http://www.juliandyke.com/Optimisation/Operations/WindowNoSortStopkey.html

Comment: Very nice! The order by is strange though, there is only one emplid here (because of the where clause). Maybe change it in the example to something else (like effdt)

Comment: Link to an asktom article on this topic (he uses Chad's approach):  http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html

Comment: @uglysmurf, I posted another "Ask Tom" article where he shows the row_number() approach, which was written 5 months after the article you show there.

Answer (score 8):

Since I did a comparison of [Chad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41665/chad-birch) and [Nick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/62985/nick) approaches to make a comment on Nick's answer, I thought I'd post my findings here.  I used Tom Kyte's [runstats](http://asktom.oracle.com/tkyte/runstats.html) package to compare them with this script:

```
begin
   runstats_pkg.rs_start('Chad');
   for i in 1..10000 loop
     for r in (
      SELECT EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
      FROM (SELECT ROWNUM rnum, EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
            FROM (SELECT EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
                  FROM JOB
                  WHERE emplid = '12345')
            WHERE rownum <= 60
      )
      WHERE rnum >= 50
      ) loop
        null;
      end loop;
   end loop;
   runstats_pkg.rs_middle('Nick');
   for i in 1..10000 loop
     for r in (
      select EMPLID, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON
      from
      (
      SELECT EMPLID, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON, row_number() over (order by emplid) rn
      from JOB where emplid ='12345'
      )
      where rn between 50 and 60
      ) loop
        null;
      end loop;
    end loop;
   runstats_pkg.rs_stop(0,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false);
end;
/
```

The results:

```
Run1 = Chad
Run2 = Nick

*** Comparative Time Report ***
Run                                   Time (hsecs)
--------------------------------------------------
Run1                                            69
Run2                                            77

Run1 ran in 89.61% of the time of Run2
Run2 ran in 111.59% of the time of Run1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Using autotrace the plans can be seen to be pretty similar:

```
SQL>           SELECT EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
  2            FROM (SELECT ROWNUM rnum, EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
  3                  FROM (SELECT EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
  4                        FROM JOB
  5                        WHERE emplid = '12345')
  6                  WHERE rownum <= 60
  7            )
  8            WHERE rnum >= 50
  9  /

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |         |     1 |    41 |     3   (0)|
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |         |     1 |    41 |     3   (0)|
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY               |         |       |       |            |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| JOB     |     1 |    13 |     3   (0)|
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | JOB2_PK |     1 |       |     2   (0)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RNUM">=50)
   2 - filter(ROWNUM<=60)
   4 - access("EMPLID"=12345)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          2  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        264  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        231  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          1  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          0  rows processed

SQL>           select EMPLID, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON
  2            from
  3            (
  4            SELECT EMPLID, EFFDT, ACTION, ACTION_REASON, row_number() over (order by emplid) rn
  5            from JOB where emplid ='12345'
  6            )
  7            where rn between 50 and 60
  8  /

no rows selected


Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                     | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT              |         |     1 |    41 |     3   (0)|
|*  1 |  VIEW                         |         |     1 |    41 |     3   (0)|
|*  2 |   WINDOW NOSORT STOPKEY       |         |     1 |    17 |     3   (0)|
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| JOB     |     1 |    17 |     3   (0)|
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN          | JOB2_PK |     1 |       |     2   (0)|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("RN">=50 AND "RN"<=60)
   2 - filter(ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY "EMPLID")<=60)
   4 - access("EMPLID"=12345)
       filter("EMPLID"=12345)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          2  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
        264  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        231  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          1  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          0  rows processed
```

It would appear that there isn't much to choose between the 2 methods, though Chad's is consistently slightly faster on my database which is:

Oracle Database 10g Release 10.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Hm. If that isn't above and beyond, then I don't know what is. ;-) +1

Comment: Yes, it's a sad indictment of my afternoon!

Answer (score 7):

It's a little tricky in Oracle, I think you have to do something like this:

```
SELECT EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
FROM (SELECT ROWNUM rnum, EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
      FROM (SELECT EMPLID,EFFDT,ACTION,ACTION_REASON
            FROM JOB
            WHERE emplid = '12345')
      WHERE rownum <= 60
)
WHERE rnum >= 50;
```

Comment: Is rownum ORDER BY sensitive?

Comment: I believe so http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255

Comment: Yeah, so an ORDER BY in the innermost query would be a very good idea, he just didn't have one in his example so I didn't want to guess at the right ordering.

Comment: I thank you all for your prompt response. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Bobby, can you mark one of these as the answer that you used?

Comment: Ive used the query provided by Nick.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ROWNUM (see [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-sep/o56asktom.html)).
If you need to control sort order, you can wrap another query around your query.

Comment: I thank you all for your prompt response. I really appreciate your help.